# I do not know what is wrong with initialization of cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cookies

Thanks to debug I know that when I execute this part of code, my cookie which key is "Cart" is still null. I do not know what is wrong, maybe configuration. I use .NET 6.0, so I do not have Startup.cs file. As far as I can see I do everything that tutorials on the Internet, so I do know what is the reason why it does not work. I use ASP NET Core MVC.

```
if (Request.Cookies[strCart] == null)
            {
                List<Cart> lsCart = new List<Cart>();
                lsCart.Add(new Cart(_context.Articles.Find(id), 1));
                cartAmount++;
                CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();
                option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
                Response.Cookies.Append(strCart, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lsCart), option);
                //Request.Cookies[strCart] is still null
            }
```

**Program.cs file:**

```
using Shop.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
builder.Services.AddSession();
builder.Services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.Name = "Shop";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1440);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

var app = builder.Build();


if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseSession();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: If you add cookies to response, this does not affect the current request. You should check the response in your browser's developer tools > network and see if the cookie is included. Then check if it was saved in your browser and then check if upcoming request include it.

Answer (score 0):

From the sample code you provided, I have tested it and found that there is no problem. It is recommended that `Request.Cookies[strCart]` be written as `Request.Cookies["strCart"]` to be easier to understand.

First of all, we need to be clear that when we request assignment, we should get null.

[image]

When the current request ends, as we can see from the gif image below, the content of the cookie is stored in the browser. After setting the cookie, trigger the request again to see the value in `Request.Cookies["strCart"]`.

**Reason:**

---

**Reproduce the issue:**

**1. My test code.**

```
   public string test()
   {
        List<Cart> lsCart = new List<Cart>();
        int cartCount = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < cartCount; i++)
        {
            Cart c = new Cart();
            c.Id = i;
            lsCart.Add(c);
        }
        CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();
        option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
        Response.Cookies.Append("strCart", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lsCart), option);
        return string.Empty;
   }
   ...
   public class Cart { 
       public int Id { get; set; }
   }
```

[image]

**2. Test result.**
[image]